# JavaScript: Pick old array by key and rename the key in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, each

I have an array of objects and I want to "pick" a new array from the value of the key `viewerId`. I also want to change the name of the `viewerId` key to `userId`. Here is what I have done with lodash:

```js
const viewerList = [{
    "id": 1,
    "viewerId": 5,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "viewerId": 8,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "viewerId": 6,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "viewerId": 9,
    "status": true
  }
]

var result = []
_.each(viewerList, (o) => {
  result.push(_.pick(o, 'viewerId'))
})

result = result.map(function(item) {
  return {
    userId: item.viewerId
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

I am doing this in two steps. Can this be optimized?

Comment: what is the problem you have?

Comment: Optimization issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the following in a single statement:

```js
const viewerList = [{
    "id": 1,
    "viewerId": 5,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "viewerId": 8,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "viewerId": 6,
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "viewerId": 9,
    "status": true
  }
]

// The same logic in a single statement
var result = viewerList.map(function(item) {
    return { userId : item.viewerId}
})

console.log(result)
```

This work on all browsers ie9 and up. For more information on the `.map()` function being used, [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose, using `map` would be the proper way to handle it, as you are transforming the existing data.

Therefore, you don't even need *lodash*.

You can take advantage of *destructuring* and *renaming* in the same step:

```
const result = viewerList.map(({ viewerId: userId }) => ({ userId }))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
viewerList.map(({viewerId}) => ({userId: viewerId}))
```

or in lodash

```
_.map(viewerList, ({viewerId}) => ({userId: viewerId}))
```